# Change height based on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the height of a div to be percentage based as opposed to pixel based, I have the below code and I'm curious how i would now change it from pixels to percentage.

The end result is I want a div to re-size its height based on a percentage of the current height of the window.

Edit: The height and width condition as per the code below isn't actually needed, but it's there for testing purposes as i was trying to find a solution.

Please forgive my naivete, I'm relatively new to JavaScript.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var h = $(window).height();
        var w = $(window).width();
        $(".gallery-container").css('height',(h < 768 || w < 1024) ? 800 : 400);
    });
});
```

Comment: did you just want to make the div 100% height of the window?

Comment: Are you referring to aspect ratios?

Comment: Since you're clearly using jQuery, I've added the `jquery` tag.

Comment: Use the proper tool for the job - CSS, not JavaScript. If you want the height based on a percentage, then why not use `height: XX%`?

Comment: I did the same by setting $('.gallery-container').height ($(window).height() - sizeForPadding_sizeForBorders_Otherfixedsizes)

Comment: @Adam The div is absolutely positioned and the div containing it has a set height (it cannot have a fluid height).

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard i was it to have a height of roughly 75% of the current window size.

Comment: @NikkiMather - google `CSS media queries`. Again, I beg of you not to use JavaScript to solve a CSS problem.

Comment: @Adam Media queries aren't going to cut it either. This needs to resize even if the height of the page is changed by a single pixel, not set in stone as it would be if i used media queries.

Comment: @NikkiMather do you want to resize the element on window resize in such a way--for example if the element's height was 40% of window before resize then it should remain 40% of the new size of  window after resize?

Comment: @UDB i found a perfect example here; http://www.ateliermanagement.com/photographers/naomi-kaltman/celebrities-01 - i basically want the exact same functionality as that (in regards to height resizing - see what i mean?). The answer i posted isn't quite what i want, but it's the closest i can get. The height should never go below 200 pixels, too.

Answer (score 0):

By the power of math!

```
var h = $(window).height();
var scale = 0.75; // This is 75%
$(".gallery-container").css('height', h * scale);
```

Comment: Hi, this looks close to what i need, but cannot get it to work for some reason - nothing triggers when i re-size the window.

Answer (score 0):

According to your JavaScript code (I'm guessing it's not exactly correct) this is the corresponding solution in CSS:

```
.gallery-container { height: 400px; }

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) or (max-height: 768px)  {
 .gallery-container { height: 800px; }
}
```

Comment: The height and width part of the code are not actually needed, I should have added that in my initial post. The height and width of the page (in terms of pixels) do not matter - i want to resize solely based on the current height of the window.

If a user resizes his or her window slightly, the div should resize automatically (even if it's by 1px).

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that seems to be working perfectly at the moment.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var newheight = $(window).innerHeight();      
   $(".gallery-container, #static ul li img").height(newheight / 2);
});
```